# How do I see the last popup?

Tags: 13.04

While I was typing a message there was a popup, which I didn't get to see.

I didn't get to see it because it stole focus and thus took my key presses as commands. (i.e. when I hit space to write a new word it thought I can hitting "OK" or "Cancel" or whatever the default was). This happened so fast that I didn't get to see what it was. Maybe it was a system update?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop.

Is it possible to see the last system messages/events?

Is it possible to change this behaviour? (e.g. stop it from stealing focus)

Any ideas as to what did might have been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CCSM** to adjust the focus stealing prevention. Open it and go to **General Options** > **Focus & Raise Behaviour**. Here you can set the **Focus Prevention Level**, normal should work fine in most cases, but you can set it to a higher level if you still have problems. Just be careful to not set it unnecessarily high as it could prevent modal popups (which need an action immediately) from gaining focus, which would cause undesirable side effects.

Comment: No, it's not notifications. It was a window and it looked like the software update, but then again no...

Comment: There's no way to see closed windows again. If it was indeed the software updater, you can simply re-run it from the Dash (just search for “Updater”.

Comment: But that's the point. I have no idea what it is. It might as well have been unity asking me if I wanted ads as my wallpaper.  Edit: so what I'm looking for is a way to find out what is was and/or make sure it doesn't happen again. Btw. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I changed my answer to match your actual problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and paste these following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recent-notifications
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

after installation , you can see your old notifications from recent.

[image]

Credit goes to Ubuntuforums and webupd8.

Comment: There is not ~/.cache/notify-osd.log file on my machine. I installed the two applications, but nothing shows up in the statusbar, and there is nothing in unity search bar or in the terminal for "recent-notifications" or "indicator-notifications"

Comment: you give restart because applet have to  load